# Go: Marshall array/slice of different types to XML

Tags: xml, go

I have a struct

```
type Response struct {
  Verbs []interface{}
}
```

and some another structs of verbs like

```
type Verb1 struct{
  Field1 string
  ...
}

type Verb2 struct{
  Field2 int
  ...
}
```

How to from object

```
&Response{Verbs: []interface{}{Verb1{}, Verb2{}, Verb1{}}}
```

to get XML like

```
<Response><Verb1>...</Verb1><Verb2>...</Verb2><Verb1>...</Verb1></Response>
```

?

I tried to use `encoding/xml` but it generates element `Verbs` too like

```
<Response><Verbs><Verb1>...</Verb1><Verb2>...</Verb2><Verb1>...</Verb1></Verbs></Response>
```

How to avoid generations of `<Verbs>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name `Verb` types explicitly.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Root struct {
    Container []interface{}
}

type A struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"A"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type B struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"B"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

func main() {
    r := Root{
        Container: []interface{}{
            A{Value: "a"},
            B{Value: "b"},
        },
    }
    text, _ := xml.Marshal(r)
    fmt.Println(string(text))
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/RZZecmzNkf)